# Fly-through GRASS GIS resolution

Tags: grass-gis, resolution, fly-through

I want to create a fly-through in GRASS GIS 3D. The problem: throughout the "flight" the rendering is at low visual resolution, while it is set a high resolution. Is there a way to render a flight sequence at high resolution (1)?

Comment: Did you set under "Data" tab the "Fine resolution" to a low number (yes, that's a bit counter-intuitive)? See also https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/wxGUI.nviz.html#data-properties

Comment: Yes. Static rendering is fine, just when I switch to fly mode it gets crude. One work-around is Meshlab/Blender, but then I need to convert all to vector data and I want to avoid that. The data set is all raster.

Comment: Try to set "Coarse resolution" to 1 as well.

Comment: Anna - thank you. That works. Makes sense, as GRASS renders "coarse" initially.